# Alternatives to LINQ.SelectMany with constant number of inner elements

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to determine if there is a better way to execute the following query:

I have a `List` of `Pair` objects.

A `Pair` is defined as

```
public class Pair
{
    public int IDA;
    public int IDB;
    public double Stability;
}
```

I would like to extract a list of all distinct ID's (ints) contained in the `List<Pair>`.

I am currently using

```
var pIndices = pairs.SelectMany(p => new List<int>() { p.IDA, p.IDB }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Which works, but it seems unintuitive to me to create a `new List<int>` only to have it flattened out by `SelectMany`.

This is another option I find unelegant to say the least:

```
var pIndices = pairs.Select(p => p.IDA).ToList();
pIndices.AddRange(pairs.Select((p => p.IDB).ToList());
pIndices = pIndices.Distinct().ToList();
```

Is there a better way? And if not, which would you prefer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Union()` to get both the A's and B's after selecting them individually.

```
var pIndices = pairs.Select(p => p.IDA).Union(pairs.Select(p => p.IDB));
```

Comment: Which would change the order they are returned in. This might not be a problem, but is worth mentioning.

Comment: Well, if it's immediately followed by `Distinct`, probably not. But this _does_ iterate `pairs` twice, which at least the `SelectMany` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, I find this the most effective and readable of the bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly shorten the inner expression to `p => new [] { p.IDA, p.IDB }`.

Comment: Creating a new array, to have it immediately flattened out by `SelectMany`, isn't much of an improvement on creating a new list.

Comment: It was not supposed to improve anything else than readability.

Answer (score 2):

This is one without a new collection:

```
var pIndices = pairs.Select(p => p.IDA)
                .Concat(pairs.Select(p => p.IDB))
                .Distinct();
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as Jon B's answer, but with the `Distinct` as a separate step and thus an extra iterator. (No -1 from me though, it's not _wrong_.)

Comment: @Rawling: I would also prefer the `Union` because it's made for this. However, the difference of both in terms of performance is negligible (16ms for `Concat+Distinct` vs. 17ms for `Union` with 1000000 pairs and 10000 iterations).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a 2-element array/list for each `Pair`, and don't want to iterate your `pairs` list twice, you *could* just do it by hand:

```
HashSet<int> distinctIDs = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    distinctIDs.Add(pair.IDA);
    distinctIDs.Add(pair.IDB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorten it like this:

```
var pIndices = pairs.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.IDA, p.IDB }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Creating a new array, to have it immediately flattened out by `SelectMany`, isn't much of an improvement on creating a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Enumerable.Repeat` is a little unorthodox, but here it is anyway:

```
var pIndices = pairs
    .SelectMany(
        p => Enumerable.Repeat(p.IDA, 1).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.IDB, 1))
    ).Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Finally, if you do not mind a little helper class, you can do this:

```
public static class EnumerableHelper {
    // usage: EnumerableHelper.AsEnumerable(obj1, obj2);
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(params T[] items) {
        return items; 
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var pIndices = pairs
    .SelectMany(p => EnumerableHelper.AsEnumerable(p.IDA, p.IDB))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But isn't it actually creating an array under the hood now?

Comment: @Rotem It certainly does, but it's more readable, and it enumerates the pairs only once.